# Unable to use SaveBinaryDirect with Sharepoint online always return 403

Tags: .net, sharepoint, shared-libraries, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-clientobject

i am new with SharePoint,

I am trying to upload a picture inside a document library by c# code.

There is my code

```
string webUrl = "https://mysharepointesite.sharepoint.com/";



  string targetSite = webUrl;
  using (ClientContext ctx = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(targetSite))
  {
    if (ctx != null)
    {
      var lib = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("mesdocuments");
      ctx.Load(lib);
      ctx.Load(lib.RootFolder);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      string sourceUrl = "C:\\temp\\picture.jpg";          
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourceUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect (ctx, lib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/myPicture.jpg", fs, true);
      }
    }
```

But i always get an 403 error.

I also verify if it was not the same issue has mentionned in this post, but i don't think it is.

https://razirais.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/how-to-fix-sharepoint-online-403-forbidden-error-while-downloading-files-using-client-object-model/

When i do it i received a 405 error, and the fiddler log show me that the request was trying to redirect the context to the authentication page.

it's there a  setting i need to enable ? Any idea what is my trouble ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have tagged it in SharePoint online, I am assuming that you are using SharePoint online only.

You need to pass the user name and password to the `ClientContext`. So, modify your code as below:

```
string webUrl = "https://mysharepointesite.sharepoint.com/";

string userName = "user.name@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "password";

using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }   

    ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

    if (ctx != null)
    {
      var lib = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("mesdocuments");
      ctx.Load(lib);
      ctx.Load(lib.RootFolder);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      string sourceUrl = "C:\\temp\\picture.jpg";          
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourceUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect (ctx, lib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/myPicture.jpg", fs, true);
      }
    }

}
```

Also, ensure that you are using the correct CSOM dll i.e using the SharePoint online CSOM SDK. Looking at your current implementation, i think you are using the client context incorrectly which is causing the error.

You can download the latest SDK from the link mentioned below or using Nuget (preferred).

If you download the SDK, then you might need to manually reference the dlls from the folder where it is installed.

Usually, if installed in the `C:` drive, the location is:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI`.

from there, you need to reference the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` files in your project.

Download link - [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Nuget package - [Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM)

Also, if you are not a fan of passing user name and password, you can use client id and client secret. To use that, you can take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47628107/862892)